# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'QuestionBuilder'

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I get the following when trying to Cast to my class:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'QuestionBuilder'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Line 204:            else  if(e.Row.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
Line 205:            {
Line 206:                QuestionBuilder drv = (QuestionBuilder)e.Row.DataItem;
Line 207:
Line 208:            }

MY CLASS:
```

===================================================

```
 [Serializable]
        public class QuestionBuilder
        {
            /// Field for connection string
            /// </summary>
            private string connectionstring = Connection.GetConnecionString();

            public string QuestionText
            {
                get;
                set;
            }


            public string DataTypeId
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string DynamicAttributeId
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public object DynamicValue
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string SortOrder
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string ProjectID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string DataTypeName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public bool QuestionID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }


            public int surveyID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string ID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string dateteupdated
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string recordstatus
            {
                get;
                set;
            }



            public string modifiedby
            {
                get;
                set;
            }


            public string changereason
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public bool Required
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string SectionName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int SectionID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string FormType
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public int DecisionsetID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int SurveyID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
    =========================================================

      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        tc.CssClass = "casetableheaderstudyList";
                    }
                }
                else  if(e.Row.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    QuestionBuilder drv = QuestionBuilder)e.Row.DataItem;

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                        tc.BorderWidth = 0;
                        //tc.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        tc.CssClass = "casetableColumsStudyList";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you binding a `List<QuestionBuilder>` to the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to visualise the problem without full mapping details and data binding code.

But, based on your post, this appears to be data mapping issue. It can happen when the DataField value of the column in question does not matches the underlying source column name.

Ex.: If one specifies DataKeyNames property as ID and the actual column name is CustomerID. It will throw the above error.

Please revisit your code with this context and see if it helps.